# Stream video from youtube

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need to stream youtube custom playlist. And each new watcher should begin watch not from playlist start, but proceed watching from a current timeline (like TV).

This playlist i'll generate by myself on a server. The current solution i can imagine it's to generate playlist for each new watcher according to a current timeline with an time offset in a current video.

Is there some another way to enable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to not use "playlists" at all (as in the actual YouTube playlist functionality).  When a user finishes watching a video, make a call to your server to see what the next video should be.  Once you know what video to show next, replace the player with the new video, and call the Play function.

To make the experience better, you could preload the next player in the background several seconds before the user finishes their current video.